# URLs in emails sent via mail() don't work / display differently in every mail client

Tags: php

I'm sending emails via `mail()` that include an URL with a variable, that allows recipients to view filtered contents only.

```
$text_body= "anglebracket_a_href='https://example.com/list.php?var=$variable'">Link anglebracket/a>"
```

Variables are stored in a mysql database. Everything works fine so far, but the URL displays differently in every mail client.

Instead of the correct version:

```
<br>
https://www.example.com/list.php?var=76733d141
```

In Thunderbird it reads

```
<br>
tps://www.example.com/list.php?varv733d141*
```

(https truncated! and = sign and the first 2 digits turn into a v)

In Webmail it reads

```
<br>
https://www.example.com/list.php?varv733d141
```

In my iPhone mail app it displays correctly and the link is clickable and works!

These are my headers:

```
$recipient = "test@example.com";
$subject="Your Login Data for $var1 at $var2 in $var3";
$text   ="";
$text   .=$text_body;
$sender   = "Test <noreply@example.com>";
$headers   = array();
$headers[] = "MIME-Version: 1.0";
$headers[] = "Content-Type: text/HTML; charset=ISO-8859-1";
$headers[] = "Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable";
$headers[] = "From: {$sender}";
$headers[] = "Reply-To: {$sender}";
$headers[] = "Subject: {$subject}";
$headers[] = "X-Mailer: PHP/".phpversion();
mail($recipient, $subject, $text,implode("\r\n",$headers));
```

Tried different encodings and delimiting and everything. Which basic or not so basic problem am I overlooking? Thanks for any help!

Comment: If you don't show us any code, all we can do is guess.

Answer (score 1):

Since you say that you're sending quoted-printable, you should actually encode it properly. The `=` character has special meaning in quoted-printable encoding. Use the [`quoted_printable_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.quoted-printable-encode.php) function to encode the body.

```
mail($recipient, $subject, quoted_printable_encode($text),implode("\r\n",$headers));
```